# How to add autofocus to surface view?

Tags: android

I am working on a QR decoder app in which i have created a `SurfaceView` to display camera output and a `ImageButton` to select an image from gallery. 
I am using google play services to decode the QR code which requires to use surface view to scan the QR using camera. But it is not focusing on its own.
Below is the code for the same.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

public class Scanner extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);

        final SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDectector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();
        final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this,barcodeDectector).setRequestedPreviewSize(1920,1080).build();
        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
        barcodeDectector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                //QRcode found hence move to intent action.
                if( barcodes.size() != 0){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Scanner.this,Verify.class);
                    i.putExtra("xml",barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });

        ImageButton scanImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.scanImage);
        scanImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //button action to be added
            }      

        });

    }
}
```

The activity_scanner.xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scanImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_48dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/camera_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try creating class which extends SurfaceView. In constructor use `setFocusable(true)`.

Comment: class CameraView extends SurfaceView{
    
                public CameraView(Context context) {
                    super(context);
                    setFocusable(true);
                }
            }
            final CameraView cameraView = (CameraView)     findViewById(R.id.camera_view);

Comment: Do you mean like this.. but now it gives casting problems

Comment: Like i mentioned in answer, Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending Surface view like this, and `setFocusable(true)`.

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Then in layout you can use this class like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://s...content-available-to-author-only...d.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://s...content-available-to-author-only...d.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<com.abhayjatindoshi.encryptorcode.qrlogin.javaclass.CameraView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dip"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scanImage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_48dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/camera_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use Layout like above.

Comment: how do i import the calls in xml,
the app crashes since CameraView is user class and is not found

Comment: In xml you have to use `<yourClassPackage.CameraView>`. `yourClassPackage` is the package where your CameraView class is present.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cameraView.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cameraView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
cameraView.setFocusable(true);
cameraView.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Above did not solved mine "focus" problem but i come a cross other solution which helped me:

```
private void setCamFocusMode(){
if(null == mCamera) {
    return;
 }

/* Set Auto focus */ 
Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
List<String>    focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)){
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);   
 } else 
 if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)){
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
 }   

 mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

oryginally posted here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27092999/6225516

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still looking for this yet, I've solved it by adding `.setAutoFocusEnabled(true)` before `.build`, in the line:

```
BarcodeDetector barcodeDectector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
    .build();*
```